# solving simultaneous congruences with unknown rests

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ be given, how to find all Integers $x$, that solve the simultaneous congruences $x\equiv a_1(mod\ 7), x\equiv a_2(mod\ 9), x\equiv a_3(mod\ 20)$

I know the chinese remainder theorem, but I am not sure of how to solve this equation efficently.

Comment: apply it twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply CRT, which yields that, modulo $7\cdot 9\cdot 20$ we have

$$ x \,\equiv\, 9\cdot 20 \left(\dfrac{1}{9\cdot 20}\bmod 7\right) a_1 + 7\cdot 20 \left(\dfrac{1}{7\cdot 20}\bmod 9\right) a_2 +  7\cdot 9 \left(\dfrac{1}{7\cdot 9}\bmod 20\right) a_3$$

To finish simply compute the above inverses.

Comment: I'm sorry I am kinda lost on what to do.

Comment: Those are not the correct inverses, e.g. $\bmod 7\!:\,\ 1 \equiv   9(20)y \equiv  2(-1)y\equiv -2y\,$ so $\, y \equiv  1/(-2) \equiv -6/(-2) =3\ $ (reply to your prior comment, now deleted).  Do you not know how to compute modular inverses, e.g. by the extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: no unfortunately I never had to do that before, and this one is a bit complex, but thanks alot for the example, I try to figure it out.